# How to get the vale of hiddenfield using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to embed below piece of snippet to get the value of hidden field customerDeviceIdReferenceCode.

```
 <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
          <input type="hidden" id="customerDeviceIdReferenceCode" name="customerDeviceIdReferenceCode"/>
        </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<#-- populate customer device id -->
            var io_bbout_element_id = 'customerDeviceIdReferenceCode'; 
            //<#-- do not install Flash        -->
            var io_install_flash = false;  
            //<#-- do not install Active X     -->
            var io_install_stm = false; 
            //<#-- do not run Active X         -->
            var io_exclude_stm = 12;   
            //<#-- enable detection of real IP -->
            var io_enable_rip = true;                               

            (function () {
                var asyncSnareScript = function() {
                    var element = document.createElement('script');
                    element.src = "https://ci-mpsnare.iovation.com/snare.js";
                    document.body.appendChild(element);

                    //function(){
                    //    var current_value = $('#customerDeviceIdReferenceCode').val();
                    //    alert(current_value);
                    //}
                };

                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener('load', asyncSnareScript, false);
                } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                    window.attachEvent('onload', asyncSnareScript);
                } else {
                    //<#-- If all else fails, just append the script immediately. -->
                    asyncSnareScript();
                }         

            })();
    </script>
    </body>
```

But when I am trying to get the value using 
     var current_value = $('#customerDeviceIdReferenceCode').val();
 it is giving me blank.
When I looked at the page source, I found a new node is created.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="QYw2oyL6KhN1E9tHbNHuW31ZS/2qIXGM4FMkKCTtafh172i2YMgOBy820zB42Z39lDPYEe/dJY4QtfDXAiA98WRBpWwpkqL0Y+aBATbVGb0=" />
    </div>
```

If I use ,
   var current_value = $('#__VIEWSTATE').val();
I can get the value.But I want to fetch the value using id customerDeviceIdReferenceCode .
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that element even has a value??

Comment: When I am using  var current_value = $('#__VIEWSTATE').val();
      just above the </script> tag I am getting the value.Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want to fetch the value using id customerDeviceIdReferenceCode

Element having `id` "customerDeviceIdReferenceCode" does not appear to have `value` attribute set at `html` , `js` ?

```
<input type="hidden" id="customerDeviceIdReferenceCode" name="customerDeviceIdReferenceCode"/>
```

Comment: Please suggest how should I proceed ?

Comment: @AnjaliNanda _"Please suggest how should I proceed ?"_ Not certain ? Add `value` attribute to `#customerDeviceIdReferenceCode` element ? Does `$('#__VIEWSTATE').val();` return expected results ? Can include `js` where `var current_value = $('#customerDeviceIdReferenceCode').val(); ` called at Question ?

Comment: $('#__VIEWSTATE').val();
 is returning expected results.
But the problem is I already have number of fields with id __VIEWSTATE in my page.

Comment: @AnjaliNanda _"$('#__VIEWSTATE').val(); is returning expected results. But the problem is I already have number of fields with id __VIEWSTATE in my page."_ Element `id` should be unique , see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id .  Can include `js` where `var current_value = $('#customerDeviceIdReferenceCode').val(); ` called at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @ guest271314 : As  I already have number of fields with id __VIEWSTATE in my page this is the reason I want to retrieve the value using #customerDeviceIdReferenceCode .
But it is giving me blank.
Help would be appreciated.